# Free Inventory management software, small DIY electronics projects

Tags: gratis, gui, electronics

Hi I am looking for some recommendations on free software that keeps an inventory of components you have and use for small DIY electronics projects. I don't need anything super advanced or professional as this is just for home and school use, however I would like something with a nice GUI if possible.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

PartKeepr is an open source inventory management project based on PHP/MySQL.
See the [PartKeepr's demo](https://demo.partkeepr.org/).

I would suggest reading this thread for more ideas: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107869/software-for-workshop-electronic-components-stock-management

If your OS is Windows and speak French, you can also have a look at the softwares developped by Patrick Bourdin: http://pat.bourdin.free.fr/: Stokouti, Petit Stock, Stokouti2.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) includes [Base](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) which is a full database management program complete with GUI capabilities and the full HSL relational database. From the blurb:

"LibreOffice Base provides wizards to help users who are new to database design (or just new to the software) to create tables, queries, forms and reports, and it comes supplied with a set of pre-defined table definitions for **tracking assets**, customers, sales orders, invoices and many other common and useful items."

LibreOffice is Free, Gatis & Open Source, will run on multiple operating systems, is available as a portable installation, (take it with you on a USB key), supports multiple [localisations](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Language_support_of_LibreOffice) (possibly more than just about anything else that I have come across).